# Load svg file from url on ImageView

Tags: android, svg, jira-rest-api

I have a URL of [this](https://kritiapps.atlassian.net/secure/viewavatar?size=xsmall&avatarId=10303&avatarType=issuetype) type for the `Jira REST API` with no `SVG` extension or file name at the end of the URL.
When opened in a browser, it shows an image.
I want to show the image in an `ImageView`, but this is not appearing to be a file path from server.

I have studied about showing an SVG into `ImageView` from `drawables` [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#code), but nothing about loading from these type of URLs.
I am using `Volley` (if that matters).

When I inspect the element in Chrome and see `Network > Response tab`, I can see `Content-Type:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8`.

How can I achieve showing image using this type of URL in an ImageView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageView only accepts Bitmaps or VectorDrawables.
An SVG is neither of the two, even if VectorDrawable descends from it.

If you don't want to use an external library to transform the SVG into a Bitmap, then I can suggest you to use a WebView to display it

---

Alternatively, you might want to convert the SVG to a VectorDrawable by using a free online tool.

Comment: I failed to use any library which picked an SVG from the provided link. I ended up using a `WebView`, as suggested. Nice workaround !

Comment: Great! One way or another we succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

**kotlin + Coil**

add dependency:

```
//Coil (https://github.com/coil-kt/coil)
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.2.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.2.0")
```

add this function to your code:

```
fun ImageView.loadSvg(url: String) {

val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
    .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@loadSvg.context)) }
    .build()

val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this.context)
    .crossfade(true)
    .crossfade(500)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
    .data(url)
    .target(this)
    .build()

imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```

Then call this method in your activity or fragment:

```
imageView.loadSvg("your_file_name.svg")
// OR imageView.loadSvg(url)
```